# how to print the value taken from user on browser in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I want to print the value taken from user to another page through jsp. the value taken is in integer. Exception error is coming that value is null. Please help me how the value will get printed?

Error Due to this line. Error is null value is taken as output.
CODE:

```
<jsp:useBean id="account" scope="session" class="com.servlet.Message1" >
 <%  String acc1 = request.getParameter("acc");
 int acc = Integer.parseInt(acc1);
 account.setAccount(acc);


 %> </jsp:useBean>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Post what have you tried? Without knowing the details it is not possible to solve you problem.

Comment: I have pasted the code for that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JSP/SimpleJSPoutput.htm):

```
//ch01_01.jsp
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>A JSP Example</TITLE>
  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <H1>Using JSP</H1>
    <% out.println("No worries."); %>
  </BODY>
</HTML>


//ch01_02.html
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Reading Text Fields</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Reading Text Fields</H1>
        <FORM ACTION="ch01_03.jsp" METHOD="POST">
            Enter your name:
            <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="text1">
            <BR>
            <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" value="Submit">
        </FORM>
    </BODY>
</HTML>

//ch01_03.jsp
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <TITLE>Reading Data From Text Fields</TITLE>
  </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Reading Data From Text Fields</H1>
        Your name is 
        <% out.println(request.getParameter("text1")); %>
   </BODY>
</HTML>

//ch01_07.jsp
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Using a Bean</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Using a Bean</H1>

    <% beans.ch01_04 messenger = new beans.ch01_04(); %>
    The bean says: <%= messenger.message() %> 

    </BODY>
</HTML>

//ch01_07.jsp
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Using Bean Properties</TITLE>
    </HEAD>

    <BODY>
        <H1>Using Bean Properties</H1>

        <jsp:useBean id="bean1" class="beans.ch01_06" />

        The bean says: <jsp:getProperty name="bean1" property="message" /> 
        <BR>
        <jsp:setProperty name="bean1" property="message" value="No Problem." />

        Now the beans says: <jsp:getProperty name="bean1" property="message" />
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It was the problem of conversion of string to int.